# synchronize on array is not showing outcome as expected

Tags: java, arrays, concurrency, locking, synchronize

```
public class ThreadDemo implements Runnable {
Integer ar [] =  new Integer[100];


@Override
public void run() {


synchronized (ar) {
    System.out.println("Start: In run method");
    for(int i =0; i<100;i++)
    {
        ar[i]=i;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<100; i++)
    {
        ar[i]= ar[i]*1000;
        System.out.println(ar[i]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println("End:in run method");
}



}
```

Other driver calls where I created two threads from the thread pool

```
Executor task   =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    task.execute(new ThreadDemo());
    task.execute(new ThreadDemo());
```

Output :

```
Start: In run method
Start: In run method
0   
0   
1000    
1000    
2000    
2000    
3000    
3000
```

Why two threads are accessing array simultaneously when array is already synchronized. Ideally when one thread access the array, it acquires the lock on that array and in this case, other thread should wait till the first thread doesnot leaves the lock on array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Synchronized` is only triggered when two or more threads try to access the SAME data. In your case, your 2 threads both run a seperate instance of the `ThreadDemo` class and hence a seperate `ar` array. So the behaviour you are seeing is as expected.

Try replacing this:

```
Executor task   =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
task.execute(new ThreadDemo());
task.execute(new ThreadDemo());
```

by this:

```
Executor task   =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
ThreadDemo td = new ThreadDemo();
task.execute(td);
task.execute(td);
```

In this case both threads are operating on the same data.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using new ThreadDemo() two times. Each thread has it's own array object. You may want to declare integer array static or choose a different implementation.